# Posting File Data Using A Base64 Encoding In ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfhttp

I am trying to send xml which contains a binary file, Base64 encoded. When I invoke `cfhttp`, my ColdFusion 10 server keeps hanging until time-out. The Visual Studio Just in Time Debugger keeps popping out.

I am using Ben Nadel's tutorial from [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1113-posting-file-data-using-a-base64-encoding-in-coldfusion.htm) post. Can someone help ?

```
  <cffunction name="_push" access="public" returntype="Any">
<!---
  Create the path to the binary file that we want to
  post via a web service.
--->
<cfset strFilePath = ExpandPath( './myfile.zip' ) />



<!--- Read in the binary file. --->
<cffile
  action="readbinary"
  file="#strFilePath#"
  variable="objBinaryData"
  />


<!---
  Create the XML that we are going to post. When posting this
  file, we are going to encode it as base64 text data.
--->
<!--- <cfsavecontent variable="strXmlData"> --->
<cfxml variable="strXmlData">
  <cfoutput>

    <file>
      <name>#XmlFormat(
        ListLast( strFilePath, "\/" )
        )#</name>

      <ext>#XmlFormat(
        ListLast( strFilePath, "." )
        )#</ext>

      <!---
        When storing the binary data, we are going to
        pass the file as a Base64 encoding. I am like
        95% sure that this will result in only valid
        XML characters, but I am not completely sure.
      --->
      <base64>#BinaryEncode(objBinaryData,"Base64")#</base64>
    </file>
  </cfoutput>
</cfxml>
<!--- </cfsavecontent> --->


<!---
  Build the URL for the "web service" to which we are going
  to post this file data.
--->
<cfset strUrl = (
  GetDirectoryFromPath(
    GetPageContext().GetRequest().GetRequestUrl().ToString()
    ) &
  "webservice.cfm"
  ) />


<cftry>

  <!--- Post the XML data to the "web service" file. --->
  <cfhttp
    url="#strUrl#"
    result="httpresponse"
    method="post"
    throwOnError="yes"
    timeout="60">

    <!--- Post XML data. --->
    <cfhttpparam
      type="xml"
      value="#strXmlData#"
      name="myxml"
      />

  </cfhttp>               

   <cfcatch type="any">
      <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" output="c:/dump-a.txt">
      <cfset httpresponse = cfcatch>
   </cfcatch>
</cftry> 


 <cfreturn httpresponse>
```

And here is the webservice.cfm file content

```
  <!--- Grab the content from the request data post. --->
  <cfset strContent = Trim( GetHttpRequestData().Content ) />
  <cfdump var="#strContent#" output="c:/webs/dump-b.txt">


  <!--- Check to see if the content is a valid XML document. --->
  <cfif IsXml( strContent )>
     <!---
        Parse the XML data into a ColdFusion Xml
        Document Object.
     --->
     <cfset xmlPost = XmlParse( strContent ) />

     <!---
        Check to see if we have all the XML nodes that we
        need in order to save the file. For our naming
        purposes, all we need is the file extension and
        the base64 data.
     --->
     <cfif (
        StructKeyExists( xmlPost.file, "ext" ) AND
        StructKeyExists( xmlPost.file, "base64" )
        )>

        <!---
           ASSERT: We have the nodes that we need, and for
           this demo, we are just going to assume that the
           data values are valid.
        --->

        <!---
           Create the file name for the target file. We are
           going to use the passed in extension and a UUID.
           Make sure that file name points to the executing
           script directory (ExpandPath()).
        --->
        <!---
        <cfset strFileName = ExpandPath(
           CreateUUID() & "." &
           xmlPost.file.ext.XmlText
           ) />
           --->
        <cfset ExpandPath( CreateUUID()&'.'& xmlPost.file.ext.XmlText) />

        <!---
           Grab the base64 file data and convert it to
           binary data.
        --->
        <cfset objBinaryData = ToBinary(
           xmlPost.file.base64.XmlText
           ) />


        <!--- Write the binary file data to disk. --->
        <cffile
           action="write"
           file="#strFileName#"
           output="#objBinaryData#"
           />           

     </cfif>

  </cfif>
```

I am testing this on my dev machine which runs on Windows 8 and ColdFusion 10 (Developer Edition).

Comment: how big is your binary object?

Comment: This particular one is 43Kb. I will have file up to 5 MB.

Comment: I think I have problem with cfhttpparam type="xml" on ColdFusion 10, I don't know why. When I changed to formfield, xml is going trough, but very slowly, it takes 30 seconds for this simple file and both services are on local dev server.

Comment: While server executes cfhttp - hangs, I am unable to run any application on server until it is finished.

Comment: probably not your problem, but you should really var scope your function variables strFilePath, objBinaryData, strXmlData, strUrl, httpresponse

Comment: Off course, this is the raw example